# How to get user's first name using alexa skills kit in Node?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Say I want to respond with "Okay xxx" or something of the sort without account linking.

Answer (score 2):

You could try asking the users's name in the first session, and then record it as a session attribute to access later. I recommend going through the Alexa tutorials found here: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Saving session attributes is covered under "Persisting Skill Attributes through DynamoDB."

Hope that helps somewhat.